# crop background image and scale as window resizes

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, sass

I am currently attempting to create a hero image on the home page of my react application.  The issue I am running into is how the image currently sits.
[image]

currently the image sits a bit more centered than I would like, I am trying to duplicate something like this(please ignore the card in front of the background image):

[image]

I am unsure of how to position the background image further to the right and down a bit without there being white-space or it looking wonky on larger screens. I would also like the image to translate to the left as a screen is resized.  The code I have attempted is as follows:

JSX

```
import React from 'react'

const Home = () => {
  return (
    <div className='h-o'>
      <div className='h-i'></div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Home
```

CSS:

```
.h-o {
  top: 181px;
  left: -44px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 644px;
  background: transparent url('../../Assets/Images/miami-courthouse.jpg') 0% 0%
    no-repeat padding-box;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

attached is a code sandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/keen-montalcini-plwgc?file=/src/styles.css

Comment: do you know about https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size , if yes, which behavior would be missing to your needs  ?

Comment: if I understand you are trying to use position `background-position: 150px 0;` as an example but then you will have to edit the size as mentioned

Comment: the issue is if i use background size cover, the image will sit as it does at the top, I am just unsure of what needs to be done to push it over to the right without there being white space accompanied with it

Answer (score 0):

To achieve what you want, you need to set `transform-origin: top left` for scale top left corner and set parent div as `overflow: hidden;` to keep it size

```css
.img-wrapper {
    display: inline-block;
    overflow: hidden;
}

img.resize {
  transform-origin: top left;
  transform:scale(1.1);
  -ms-transform:scale(1.1); /* IE 9 */
  -moz-transform:scale(1.1); /* Firefox */
  -webkit-transform:scale(1.1); /* Safari and Chrome */
  -o-transform:scale(1.1); /* Opera */
}
```

```html
<div class="img-wrapper">
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/aDExJLE.png" />
</div>
<div class="img-wrapper">
    <img class="resize" src="https://i.imgur.com/aDExJLE.png" />
</div>
```

Comment: this doesn't seem to achieve what I was looking for....